# How java swing draws to screen from different operating systems?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I know Swing use Java2d which extends AWT to draw on screen but, what low level toolkit is used by swing to render? GTK or QT for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concrete implementations of [`Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) on each supported platform direct painting to a heavyweight peer component provided by the host, e.g. [Quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(graphics_layer)) on Mac OS X, [Graphics Device Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface) on Windows, and Xlib/XCB, part of the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) often used on Linux.